# How to use selenium and poltergeist together in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, poltergeist

I have a rich frontend in my application. Some of my tests not works well with poltergeist, because of animations and AJAX requests, but works fine with selenium.

How can i use them together in one project and in one test session?

Comment: Thanks, but i want run it in one test session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the standard RSpec configuration with Capybara (require 'capybara/rspec') then you can override the normal driver that would be used for a given test with `:driver` metadata

```
it "should do something", driver: :selenium do
  # will use the selenium driver for this test
end

it "should do something else", driver: :poltergeist do
  # will use the poltergeist driver for this test
end
```

that could also be specified on the enclosing feature if you want the whole feature to use a specific driver

```
feature "blah balh", driver: :selenium do
  # all scenarios here would use the selenium driver unless overridden with their own :driver metadata
```

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

Created macros in spec/support/selenium_macros.rb:

```
module SeleniumMacros
  def use_selenium_webdriver
    before(:all) do
      Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
      Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    end

    after(:all) do
      Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
      Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
    end
  end
end
```

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.extend SeleniumMacros, type: :feature # add macros for acceptance tests
```

using example
spec/features/example_feature_spec.rb

```
feature 'Add files to question' do

  use_selenium_webdriver
```

this feature will be work with selenium, after it will be executed it activates poltergeist webdriver.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: The ability is already builtin to the normal RSpec config so this is unnecessary -  see my answer